# Using MAP_POPULATE for writing to file

Tags: c, linux, mmap

My application writes dumps huge files to disk. For various reasons it is more convenient to use `mmap` and memory writes than using the `fwrite` interface.

The slow part of writing writing to a file in this way are page faults. Using `mmap` with `MAP_POPULATE` is supposed to help; from the man page:

```
MAP_POPULATE (since Linux 2.5.46)
    Populate (prefault) page tables for a mapping.  For a file mapping, this causes read-ahead on the file.  This will help  to
    reduce blocking on page faults later.  MAP_POPULATE is supported for private mappings only since Linux 2.6.23.
```

<sub>(To answer the obvious question: I've tested this on relatively recent kernels, on 4.15 and 5.1).</sub>

However, this does not seem to reduce pagefaults while **writing** to the mapped file.

Minimal example code: test.c:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int exit_with_error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main() {
    const size_t len = 1UL << 30;
    const char *fname = "/tmp/foobar-huge.txt";

    int f = open(fname, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644);
    if(f == -1) {
        exit_with_error("open");
    }
    int ret = ftruncate(f, len);
    if(ret == -1) {
        exit_with_error("ftruncate");
    }
    void *mem = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_POPULATE, f, 0);
    if(mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        exit_with_error("mmap");
    }
    ret = close(f);
    if(ret == -1) {
        exit_with_error("close");
    }

    memset(mem, 'f', len);
}
```

When running this under a profiler or using `perf stat` it's clearly visible that the `memset` at the end triggers (many) pagefaults.
In fact, this program is **slower** when `MAP_POPULATE` is passed, on my machine ~1.8s vs ~1.6s without `MAP_POPULATE`. The difference simply seems to be the time it takes to do the populate, the number of page faults that `perf stat` reports is identical.

A last observation is that this behaves as expected when I *read* from the file, instead of writing -- in this case the `MAP_POPULATE` reduces the number of pagefaults to almost zero and helps to improve performance drastically.

Is this the expected behavior for `MAP_POPULATE`? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Since you're interested in **writing** a file, I don't see the point of using MAP_POPULATE, which is intended to speed up **reading**...

Comment: @JL. Sanchez Maybe I'm blind, but where does it say that it's only intended to speed up reading?

Comment: **For a file mapping, this causes read-ahead on the file**

Comment: Yes, that's what the man page says. But it does not say, that it does prefaulting pages is ineffective when writing to them. This is really the gist of my question btw., so if you're certain, then please write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because although the pages have been prefaulted by MAP_POPULATE, they are not dirty pages. Therefore, when writing to these pages, the CoW page faults would be triggered to set the page entries as dirty and writable.